# Active Directory password policy

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm using a foreach statement in .Net(C#) that takes users from a user list and adding them to active directory.I have 89 users, their properties(given name, surname, sAMAccountname, password) are similar but unique. However, when inserting the 86-th user or so, I get an error message that the password does not meet the policy requirements. How can this be, when this user's password is EpwrID86, and previously correctly inserted user's password was EpwrID85??

Is there something that I dont know about password policy? Maybe if the acitve directory discovers that too many password follow a pattern it throws an error? Where can I configure this not to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. It was just as it said, the password didn't respect the password policy. To view password policy go to group policy management, then search for password policy in the tree.
My problem was that part of the user's sAMAccountname was in the password(2 consecutive characters), which is not allowed by the policy.